# Java Network application cache dependencies locally

Tags: java, networking

I have several Java apps that run directly from the a shared drive on the LAN. This has worked fine until recently when we setup a remote office on a VPN. The actual applications are small, but have nearly 20 megs of dependencies in their classpath.

Is there a way to continue to run the applications from the network, but cache the dependent jars on the local machine?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Need more info about "setup a remote office on a VPN".

Comment: Does that mean you have home computer connected to your office network drives using VPN and java application is launched in memory of your local windows system?

Comment: How do you launch your java application (Execute JAR/Batch file/Ant script, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some unanswer doubts about your question. For now I would recommend below solution.

- Use Ant script to launch your java
  applications
- Reserve a folder on local drive to cache
  libraries and have it on classpath in
  ant script
- Before launching application, have
  `sync` ant-task that will synchronize
  libraries from network drive to your
  cache.
- Use libraries from cache location in
  class path instead of libraries from
  network drive

**ant sync task** helps you overwrites all files in destination with newer files from source and deletes files from destination that are not present in source.

**Reference:**

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sync.html

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html